# Which files to edit for HTML/CSS in my application (ruby)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made my application with the following introduction:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Now I want to make it more colourful etc (CSS f.eg).
I found now the JavaScript and CSS files, but I dont know which file are responsible for the editing.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Which file should I use for editing the websites?

Comment: The scss files tell me that they are using sass as a preprocessor - looks like you shouldn't be editing the css at all, but rather the scss files. They will in the end probably all be combined to the one application.css file

Comment: @deadfishli So I should do everything in application.css?
But where is my "HTML" file?

Comment: I don't know the guide, and I don't know what exactly you want to accomplish. But I think you should not be working in the applciation.css but in the "real" source files, the scss files. But then you would need to compile those after you're done editing. Check out http://sass-lang.com/ to learn more about sass.

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, "Getting Started", that was just the introduction to Rails framework and how MVC works.

At the end, there's a section [`What's next?`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#what-s-next-questionmark). Follow the tutorial link there and all your doubts will be cleared.

Hint: There's much more to Rails..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do styling and some javascript you need to do it in
**application.css** under assets/stylesheets/ and for **JS**
**application.js** under asstes/javascripts/

Comment: But if I paste some css code in appication.css, it doesn't do anything. Why?

Comment: have you included application.css file into your layout/application.html.erb file.
It should be like this under head tag
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>

Answer (score 0):

You can also add some custom.css.scss file in app/assets/stylesheets and add your code there. In this file you can use custom styles, as far as application.css is concerned it will style the complete application. I hope this helps.